# jquery email validation for valid email addresses like gmail.com

Tags: jquery, validation, email

```
 $('#reg_submit').click(function () {
               var reg_email = $('#reg_email').val();


 var errorMessage = '';
 if (reg_email == '') {
 errorMessage = "please enter email";
 $('#msg_regemail').html(errorMessage).show();
} else {
if ((!(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/im.test(reg_email)))) {
errorMessage ="please enter valid email id" ;
$('#msg_regemail').html(errorMessage).show();
} else {
 $('#msg_regemail').html('').hide();
} 
}
```

i had this code for checking empty email field and invalid email format.but now my requirement is to validate email addresses like gmail.com,yahoo.com.
if i enter xyz@xy.com,it should display error message like invalid email.so the jquery should only accept email ids like gmail.com etc..
can anyone suggest the code for the above requirement.
thanks in advance

Comment: Nine questions asked and NO accepted answers.  You really need to fix that.  People will stop paying attention to your questions and you aren't rewarding people who help you and you aren't contributing to the SO community by indicating which answer best helped you.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just checking simple email addresses, you can use this regex to extract the domain and then check it against a premade list.  You could also make an illegal list and check against that too.

```
var legalDomains = {
    "-yahoo.com": true,
    "-gmail.com": true,
    "-hotmail.com": true,
    "-msn.com": true
};

var matches = reg_email.match(/@(.*)$/);
if (matches) {
    // matches[1] is the part after the @ sign in the email address
    if (("-" + matches[1]) in legalDomains) {
        // found the domain in the permitted list
    }
}
```

Note: the leading "-" is used in the list to make sure we never match any built-in method names on the javascript object like "keys" or "create" by accident which give the wrong answer for certain words.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rTzUd/

Comment: why the use of "-" ? any particular reason?

Comment: @sabithpocker - Did you see the "Note" at the end of my answer?

Comment: got it :) so otherwise we should use hasOwnProperty when using 'in'  right?

Comment: @sabithpocker - I guess you could just use `hasOwnProperty()` by itself (not with `in`).

Comment: Haaa yes, i just thought of filtering only own properties inside 'for in' loop, the context when i learned hasOwnProperty :)

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this: **Working version:** http://jsfiddle.net/Uummr/2/show/ **code** http://jsfiddle.net/Uummr/2/

All you need a source of legal domains that are allowed and rest will work like charm. It will not accept any otehr email apart from the legal email in this case i.e. `var emailLegalReg =  /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!aol.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;`

*Read this:* (I have done opposite of this) http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/email-validation-using-jquery/

Hope this helps the cause `:)`

**code**

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btn-submit').click(function() {  

                $(".error").hide();
                var hasError = false;
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                var emailLegalReg =  /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!aol.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

                var emailaddressVal = $("#UserEmail").val();
                if(emailaddressVal == '') {
                    $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                } else if(!emailReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {    
                    $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                } else if(emailLegalReg.test(emailaddressVal)) {    
                    $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error">No eamil apart from gmail, hotmail or yahoo is allowed.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }

                if(hasError == true) { return false; }
                else {
                    $("#UserEmail").after('<span class="error">Email accepted.</span>');
                    return false;
                }
    });    
});
```

**Working image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more complex one(not authored by me but I uses this)

```
if(/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)){
validated = true;
}
```

Are you looking for specific domains as @jfriend suggests?